Inverse of a convex combination of matrices
Let $A\in\mathcal{A}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an invertible matrix and $\mathcal{A}$ a convex polytope with vertices $\{A_1, \dots, A_k\}$, that is
\begin{equation}
A = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i A_i,
\end{equation}
with $\sum \lambda_i = 1$, $\lambda_i \geq 0$ $\forall i$.
Suppose all $\{A_i\}$ are also invertible. My question is: will $A^{-1}$, in general, belong to a corresponding polytope?, i.e.
\begin{equation}
A^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \bar{\lambda}_i A_i^{-1},
\end{equation}
with $\bar{\lambda}$ possibly different than $\lambda$ but sharing the same properties (that is $\sum \bar{\lambda}_i = 1$, $\bar{\lambda}_i \geq 0$ $\forall i$).
I have tried to work with the convex combination and try to find a condition on the $\bar{\lambda}_i$ by equating the two conditions:
\begin{equation}
A^{-1} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i A_i\right)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \bar{\lambda}_i A_i^{-1},
\end{equation}
but I get automatically stuck. Any help/hits will be super appreciated. Thanks!

Not necessarily. As an example, consider
$$
A_1 = I_3, \quad A_2 = \pmatrix{1&1&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1},
$$
where $I_3$ denotes a size-3 identity matrix. We have
$$
A_1^{-1} = I_3, \quad A_2^{-1} = \pmatrix{1&-1&1\\0&1&-1\\0&0&1},\\
\left(\frac 12 A_1 + \frac 12 A_2 \right)^{-1} = \pmatrix{1 & -1/2 & 1/4\\0&1&-1/2\\0&0&1}.
$$
It's easy to see that $\left(\frac 12 A_1 + \frac 12 A_2 \right)^{-1}$ is not a linear combination of $A_1^{-1}$ and $A_2^{-1}$, let alone a convex combination.

Super clear counter-example. Many thanks for that, I'm accepting the answer. You think this can hold with some additional conditions on the ${A_i}$?

@controllystuff By the Cayley Hamilton theorem, we can at least guarantee the existence of a suitable linear (but not necessarily convex) combination for the vertices ${1,A,A^2,\dots,A^{n-1}}$. Perhaps taking a large enough number of powers of $A$ will give you what you're looking for. Keep in mind, however, this would necessarily give you a polytope in which every pair of matrices $A,B \in \mathcal A$ satisfies $AB = BA$, so in this way this answer might not be "interesting".

@controllystuff In coming up with more interesting necessary conditions, it might be helpful to note that
$$
(\lambda_1 A_1 + \lambda_2 A_2)^{-1} = \lambda_1A_1 (I + t(A_1^{-1}A_2))^{-1},
$$
where we note that $(I + tM)^{-1}$ gives us some kind of polynomial over $M$ (either by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem or, more heuristically, with the Neumann series expansion).

many thanks. Very useful. I think I can manage to use this for my particular case.
